# TableSorter clickable but not sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I'm using TableSorter... after some tweaking and searching on SO, i got somewhere, but still having an issue.

My table is showing and the headers are clickable (with the corresponding arrows) but the data is not actually sorting.

Im thinking it's because the data that's being pulled in is PHP... on the other hand, its rendering as pure HTML and the TableSorter should just modify the rendered HTML, not the server side PHP. anyway.

here's the rendered code - its clickable but not sorting. any ideas??

`enter code here`http://jsfiddle.net/4eLyj4gr/3/

Comment: All columns seem to be sorting with the exception of `First Name`. Is that the behavior you're trying to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. I had PHP rendering too many `<tbody>`s.... that messed it up. only have one `<tbody>` and one `</tbody>` and it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

All the columns sorted or at least tried to sort for me accept for the first name column. However you were setting your headers up incorrectly. you had

```
 headers : {
   // set "sorter : false" (no quotes) to disable the column
   0: { sorter: "text" },
   1: { sorter: "digit" },
   2: { sorter: "text" },
   3: { sorter: "url" }
},
```

it should be changed to

```
  headers : {
    // set "sorter : false" (no quotes) to disable the column
    0: { sorter: "text" },
    1: { sorter: "text" },
    2: { sorter: "text" },
    4: { sorter: "url" }
},
```

as column 0 is your last name column 1 is your first name column 2 is an email which are all text column 3 is the money and if you do not include it jquery does its best to interpret which in this case works better than using the digit since its money. Doing that the jsfiddle works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/4eLyj4gr/4/